# Wireless connection hangs after wakeup

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, microsoft-surface-pro

I have an interesting problem with the WLAN connection of my surface pro 3: When I close the device it hybernates. When I wake the device up from hybernating, it remembers the last wlan connection, but it does not refresh it.

For example when I'm on work, I'm connected to the wlan at my workplace. I close the computer, go open, wake it up - and it still says it is connected to my workplace wlan, even though I'm miles away from work and definitely have no reception.

The device does not drop these connections. It tries to send, after some time it adds a message that I have limited connectivity, but it will still show the nonexistent wlan as being connected.

Only when I manually drop the connection it will connect to my home wlan.

It does the same when I'm at home and wake the device from hybernating, only here it is not as obvious as when I switch locations. Still, after waking up it will say it is still connected but has limited connectivity. Only manual reconnecting will fix it. Even when I change the connection not to automatically connect to this network it will still hold the connection after waking up.

So it seems my wlan adapter does not refresh the connection on waking up - any idea how to fix this? I already installed all updates, downloaded the november driver package and reinstalled the wireless driver to no avail.

[Update]

I reinstalled Windows 8.1 with update from scratch, and wireless worked as it should.

But: After installation Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition including Windows Phone SDK, wireless again did not work.
The Visual Studio installation enabled Hyper-V, and this seemed to be the cause. Disabling it made wireless work again as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had issues with the wifi on the Surface PRO 3 after installing Visual Studio, until I completely disabled Hyper-V. For that, simply run from an elevated command prompt:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

See also a [discussion](http://winsupersite.com/mobile-devices/surface-pro-3-tip-hyper-v-vs-connected-standby) about *Hyper-V* conflicting with *Connected Standby* and how to disable it. You might also prefer the solution proposed by [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx) to add an additional entry in the boot menu to selectively start Windows with/without Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

After analyse your problem you do this step

1. Open command prompt with administrative rights.
2. Execute the following commands:

   > netsh int tcp set heuristics disabled
   >   netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
   >   netsh int tcp set global rss=enabled
3. Then show the settings using this command:

   > netsh int tcp show global
4. Reboot your system and test if the problem is gone or not.

Comment: Did the commands, still the same problem. I add the output to the question (better formatting).

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was Hyper-V.

The Installation of Visual Studio activated Hyper-V. As soon as I deactivated Hyper-V, the Problems with wireless connections disappeared.

Comment: What would be of interest now, is how can we get Hyper-V work with the WLAN connection on the Surface PRO 3. I have been consistently experiencing wifi connection issues on the tablet where it cannot get an IP address assigned through DHCP. And this makes any useful work impossible, as no matter how often I tried to deconnect and reconnect manually, turning off and on again, etc. -- nothing fixed this.

Comment: Pierre, do you only have the problems when Hyper-V is activated?
I don't need Hyper-V, so I have no inclination for digging in deeper.

Comment: No, just the wifi connection problems. And a colleague with a Surface PRO 3 has the same issues as I have. I simply disabled Hyper-V and am happy now.